# How to configure Nginx to load wordpress site in subfolder? (for api calls)

Tags: nginx, wordpress, subdomain, directory

My project directory structure is as follows:

`/var/www/mysite/
    backend/
    frontend/`

where `frontend/` contains simple html and js files, and `backend/` is a wordpress site. I expose wordpress data to a REST api endpoint for the frontend.

I want to have mysite.com show the html/js files and all REST api calls are made to `mysite.com/api` which are the wordpress site files. (so `mysite.com/api/wp-admin` will also work as normal).

I am having trouble configuring nginx to make this possible. This is my current configuration:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           mysite.com www.mysite.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

  root  /var/www/mysite/frontend;

  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

location ^~ /api {
    root /var/www/mysite/backend;

    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /../backend/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

      # With php5-cgi alone:
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      # With php5-fpm:
      #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

  sendfile off;
}
```

This just downloads the index.php file from wordpress when I try to access the URL mysite.com/api. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that your configuration assumes that WordPress is installed at `/var/www/mysite/backend/api`. Using the `root` directive, the URI prefix is always part of the local pathname.

Use the `alias` directive to remove the `/api` element from the pathname. For example:

```
location ^~ /api {
    alias /var/www/mysite/backend;

    index index.php;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /api/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

We avoid using `try_files` with `alias` due to this [long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below for WP in a sub-folder:

```
    location /backend {
            rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /backend/$2 break;
            rewrite ^/backend/(.*)$ /backend/index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
```